# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package python

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask, модульность, импорт

У меня вот такая структура проекта

```
---package1/code.py
---package2/ext.py
```

Как мне импортировать переменную из ext.py в code.py ?

`from ext import var` - не срабатывает, говорит что не существует модуля ext

`from ..package2.ext import var` - тоже не срабатывает выдаётся ошибка: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1153658/importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)

Answer (score 3):

Всё работает.

1. В файлах указывать `import` и `from` без ведущих точек:

   ```
   from package2.ext import var
   ```

   а не

   ```
   from ..package2.ext import var
   ```
2. Вызывать нужно из папки **ваш_проект** вот такую команду:

   ```
   python -m package1.code
   ```

Можно путь к **python** указать полностью, типа `usr/bin/python`.
Важно указать `-m` и точку `.` между `package1` и `code`, а не `/`, и после `code` не писать `.py`.

Вот так:

```
путь_к_вашему_проекту> python -m package1.code
```

Answer (score 1):

Python просматривает список каталогов определенный в `sys.path`.

Ошибка: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` говорит о том что модуль не был найден в `sys.path` (вывод ее на печать поможет прояснить ситуацию).

При такой структуре желательно использовать `main.py` для запуска и импорта дочерних модулей:

```
project_folder/
   main.py
   package1/
      __init__.py
      code.py
   package2/
      __init__.py
      ext.py
```

Если вам нужно запустить `code.py` и при этом импортировать данные из `ext.py`, то нужно:

- запустить `code.py` как модуль `python -m package1.code`
- или добавить `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` в самое начало `code.py`

Comment: `Ошибка: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package говорит о том что модуль не был найден в sys.path` - нет, она говорит что была попытка использовать относительный импорт в модуле, не входящем в какой-либо пакет (with no known parent package), ну или из модуля импортированного/запущенного как отдельный файл, а не как модуль пакета

Answer (score 0):

- в пакетах package1 и package2 должен быть пустой файл `__init__.py` (если его нет)
- такая структура будет:

```
ваш_проект/
   package1/
      __init__.py
      code.py
   package2/
      __init__.py
      ext.py
```

- я тестировал на таких файлах:

**code.py**

```py
var = "code.py"
```

**ext.py**

```py
from package1.code import var
print(var) # выводит code.py
```

P.S. Надеюсь чем-то помогло

Comment: попробовал с пустым __init__.py и все равно та же ошибка

Comment: У меня тоже есть \_\_init\_\_.py и ошибка остаётся