# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки, модули, python-import

Есть пакедж такой структуры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально [этот проект был написан](https://github.com/thisismedium/python-xmpp-server) на питоне 2, и я портирую его на питон 3. Прошелся по нему:

```bsh
2to3 -w *.py && rm *.bak
```

Переделал некоторые более тонкие вещи (вроде  как переименование в itertools). И теперь возникает ошибка (при импорте):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .interfaces import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Как исправить?
**P.S.** Ответ на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089222/importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package-python) вопрос мне не помог, так что это не дупликат.

Comment: А на этот и связанный с ним https://stackoverflow.com/q/60593604?

Comment: А точка точно нужна перед interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз помогло, оформлю как ответ.

Точка тут похоже лишняя и именно она является причиной ошибки:

```
from .interfaces import *
     ^
```

Ну и напомню заодно, что `import *` - это вообще говоря плохой стиль, мало ли что внутри пакета есть, что может пересечься с другими объектами программы. Лучше делать конкретные, только необходимые включения функций из пакета, либо просто импортировать сам пакет и обращаться к его объектам через его имя. :)